# Persian Numbers in niklasravnsborg / laravel-pdf

Tags: laravel, mpdf, laravel-7

i used niklasravnsborg / laravel-pdf library for pdf export and its ok for words
but i cant fix numbers in this
numbers show in english fonts:
[image]

[image]

but when i comment useOTL The Number are correct but words show clutter
[image]
[image]

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve problem.
I use this function for convert numbers when i pass data to template.

```
function persian_digits($str) {

    $newstring = str_replace(array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'), array('۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹'), $str);

    return $newstring;

}
```